# How to perform multiple updates in single statement?

Tags: spring, database, postgresql, spring-boot, database-performance

I've searching online everywhere but didn't find a good answer to my problem.

We are using spring boot as framework and JPA. DB as postgres.

I would like to notch up our DB performance regarding updates and do a single statement for as following:

`UPDATE myTable SET name=it.name FROM (VALUES (132, 'David'), (913, 'Gilmour'), ...) as it (id, name) WHERE myTable.id=it.id`

My values amount are dynamic but not the columns.. Every time X objects are being passed to the function - `List`.

Using batch updates in JPA is creating multiple update statements and not a single one.

Tried to find a way using custom query with `@Query` and `@Modifying` but can we use a list as parameter in this case?

```
// Just an idea
@Query(value= "UPDATE myTable SET name = :objs[].name WHERE id=:objs[].id")
void updateNames(List<MyData> objs);
```

Found the nice `reWriteBatchedInserts` parameter for inserts which convert our batch (multiple insert statements) of `INSERT`s to a single one. But nothing for update, isn't it ?

Tried `EntityManager.createNativeQuery` but I've read that it better not doing it because of cache issues and such, and also ran in a few issues with the transactional and timeout of getting new transactions when it was called a lot of times by different threads - If this is the only solution I will dig deeper and make it work good.

Is there a spring way to do what I want ?
Or any other suggestion for better solution?